# I have tried to split a long equation using different commands e.g split, align etc but it still didn't work for me

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, split

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q_{\omega,sl}(z_p)=\frac{k_v^2\Theta\left(\omega,T_s\right)}{\pi^2}
Re\left(i\varepsilon_{rs}^{\prime\prime}(\omega)\int_{0}^{\infty}{k_\rho d k_\rho\int_{z_s}^{z_{s+1}}{dz_s}}
\left(g_{sl\rho\rho}^E\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)g_{sl\theta\rho}^{H^\ast}\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)
+g_{sl\rho z}^E\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)g_{sl\theta z}^{H^\ast}\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)
-g_{sl\theta\theta}^E\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)g_{sl\rho\theta}^{H^\ast}\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)
\right)\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer that's overall quite similar to [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654775/5001), mainly in that I also suggest splitting the long equation across 4 lines. I then employ an `aligned` environment to align the bottom 3 lines relative to one another. Next, since TeX doesn't allow `\left...\right` to cross rows, I suggest using `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` for the "outer" large parentheses and `\Bigl[` and `\Bigr]` for the "inner" large parentheses. In addition, I would get rid of the 7 [!] remaining `\left...\right` pairs, which do nothing at all except create code clutter and mess up the horizontal spacing. Finally, would you agree that it's easier to write `''` instead of `^{\prime\prime}`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for split and aligned environments

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q_{\omega,sl}(z_p)
&=\frac{k_v^2\Theta(\omega,T_s)}{\pi^2}\,
  \Re\biggl[\,
  i\varepsilon_{rs}''(\omega)
  \int_{0}^{\infty}\!k_\rho \,dk_\rho 
  \int_{z_s}^{z_{s+1}}\!dz_s\\
&\qquad
  \begin{aligned}\times\Bigl[\,
       &g_{sl\rho\rho}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)\,
        g_{sl\theta\rho}^{H^\ast} (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)  \\
  {}+{}&g_{sl\rho z}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)\,
        g_{sl\theta z}^{H^\ast}(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)  \\
  {}-{}&g_{sl\theta\theta}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)\,
        g_{sl\rho\theta}^{H^\ast}(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)
  \Bigr] \smash[t]{\biggr]}
  \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick question, how is your picture much clearly than @Zarko's?

Comment: @DialFrost - Are you asking how I create screenshots? I'm on a 16" MacBook Pro laptop, I currently use MacTeX2022 along with TeXworks, and I also use Adobe Reader as a pdf file viewer. When I have a pdf file with a LaTeX formula I like, I hit Command-P to switch from TeXworks to Adobe Reader, and then select the resolution such that just the material I want to include in the screenshot is visible on screen. I then click Command-Shift-4 and create the required rectangle by moving my fingers across the trackpad. When I raise the finger from the trackpad, the screenshot is created as a png file.

Comment: Hmm strange how your picture is *way clearer* than anyone else's :P

Comment: @DialFrost - I've noticed this difference in clarity as well. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

IN equation you need manually insert breaking points. In above showed equation is used `multlined` math environment defined in the `mathtools`  package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
q_{\omega,sl}(z_p)
    = \frac{k_v^2\Theta (\omega,T_st){\pi^2}
            Re\biggl[i \varepsilon_{rs}^{\prime\prime}(\omega)\int_{0}^{\infty}{k_\rho d k_\rho\int_{z_s}^{z_{s+1}}{dz_s}}   \\
            \biggl(g_{sl\rho\rho}^E\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)g_{sl\theta\rho}^{H^\ast}
                    (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega ) +  \\
            g_{sl\rho z}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)g_{sl\theta z}^{H^\ast}
                   (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega) -    \\
            g_{sl\theta\theta}^E (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega) g_{sl\rho\theta}^{H^\ast} (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)\biggr)\biggr]
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

or by use of the `split` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q_{\omega,sl}(z_p)
     = {}   &  \frac{k_v^2\Theta (\omega,T_st)} {\pi^2}
                Re\biggl[i\varepsilon_{rs}^{\prime\prime}(\omega)\int_{0}^{\infty}{k_\rho d k_\rho\int_{z_s}^{z_{s+1}}{dz_s}}\cdot  \\
            & \biggl(g_{sl\rho\rho}^E\left(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega\right)g_{sl\theta\rho}^{H^\ast}
                    (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega )        \\
            & + g_{sl\rho z}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)g_{sl\theta z}^{H^\ast}
                   (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)          \\
            & - g_{sl\theta\theta}^E (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega) g_{sl\rho\theta}^{H^\ast} (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)\biggr)\biggr]
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alademighty, you are welcome! BTW, you got three answers, it is time to consider to accept one (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer), which you the most liked :-)

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [@Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)'s answer. I tend not to insert spacing commands, apart from separating differentials in integrals, and sometimes in root signs.  In situations as the one in question I like the combination of \multline and \aligned. Purely a matter of taste, I guess.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for split and aligned environments

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  q_{\omega,sl}(z_p)
  =\frac{k_v^2\Theta(\omega,T_s)}{\pi^2}
  \Re\biggl[
  i\varepsilon_{rs}''(\omega)
  \int_{0}^{\infty}k_\rho\,dk_\rho 
  \int_{z_s}^{z_{s+1}}\,dz_s\\
  \begin{aligned}
    &\times\Bigl[g_{sl\rho\rho}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)
    g_{sl\theta\rho}^{H^*} (k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)  \\
    &+g_{sl\rho z}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)
    g_{sl\theta z}^{H^*}(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)  \\
    &-g_{sl\theta\theta}^E(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)
    g_{sl\rho\theta}^{H^*}(k_\rho,z_p,z_s,\omega)
    \Bigr] \smash[t]{\biggr]}
  \end{aligned}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for sticking with `\smash[t]{\biggr]}`. :-)

Comment: Yeah, nice touch ;)  BTW, your image has much higher resolution than mine, so that's where the higher clarity may be coming from.